# How to scan words in a text without newline character?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have serious issues to understand how the scanner class works. Indeed, I would like from this input:

AAAA BBBG GREZZ

ADFG GTRE

FREZZ

to have this ouput as an ArrayList:
[AAAA, BBBG, GREZZ, ADFG, GTRE, FREZZ]

My code is the following:

```
System.out.println("list of words?");
Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
scan3.useDelimiter("[\\s+\\n]");
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scan3.hasNext()){
  String temp = scan3.next();
  if(temp.equals("STOP")){
     break;
  }else{
     test.add(temp);
  }
}
System.out.println(test);
```

My input is:

AAAA BBBG GREZZ

ADFG GTRE

FREZZ STOP

And my ouput is:
[AAAA, BBBG, GREZZ, , ADFG, GTRE, , FREZZ]

My question is twofold:

- Why do I have an empty element inserted in the list (which is I beleive related to the new line)?
- As you might have noticed, I add the string "STOP" at the end in order to stop the loop because the condition scan3.HasNext() always returns "true", is it the only way to proceed?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String#split()` with a suitable delimiter (it sounds like in this case you just need `"[ \\n]+"` (that's a space and a \n) but you may want to tweak that a bit, for example you might want to split on all whitespace.

The reason for the empty entry in the list is because you are just scanning for a single character of whitespace. This gets matched twice when you have two line endings next to each other. You need to modify the regex so it matches more than one character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But to use `String.split()`, I need first to get the complete string but to do so I need to scan my text so it does not improve the code, does it?
After modifying my regex as you said, I do not have empty entry anymore, but I do not understand your explanation: 
`you have two line endings next to each other`: How is it possible?

Comment: AAAA BBBG GREZZ

ADFG GTRE

There are 2 line endings between those two lines, so when you split it finds the empty string on the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `+` appears to be in the wrong place. Try instead using `scan3.useDelimiter("[\\s\\n]+");`

Regarding,

> As you might have noticed, I add the string "STOP" at the end in order to stop the loop because the condition scan3.HasNext() always returns "true", is it the only way to proceed?

What other way would you wish to proceed? What other stop condition do you propose to use?

Comment: First thank you for your answer. Regarding the stop condition, it actually do not see any other way to do this but it looks like patch-up job to me. 
The thing is that I do not understand why `scan3.HasNext()` returns true when there is nothing more (and I pressed the `Enter` button)

Comment: @user3125129: because if it did returned false, then it would be completely non-functioning, because it would be unable to wait for user input. How would it differentiate between awaiting for input and done with input? Think on this a little bit and it will be clear to you.